# how to show time picker in 12hours format in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using this version: jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js 2.5.1. Here I am getting 24 hours format using hours12:false properties, but I want to show

'00:00 PM',
                        '01:00 PM',
                        '01.30 PM',
                        '02:00 PM',
                        '03:00 PM',
                        '04:00 PM',
                        '05:00 PM',
                        '06:00 PM',
                        '07:00 PM',
                        '08:00 PM',
                        '09:00 PM',
                        '10:00 PM',
                        '11:00 PM',
                        '12:00 PM',
                        '01:00 AM',
                        '02:00 AM',
                        '03:00 AM',
                        '04:00 AM',
'05:00 AM',
'06:00 AM'

Now I am getting 24 hours clock format 1 to 24, But I don't want 1 to 24. I need above format.

I am using this plug in http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Clean-jQuery-Date-Time-Picker-Plugin-datetimepicker.html. please help with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HH for 24 hour format and hh for 12 hour format.

```
$(function () {
    $('#startTime, #endTime').datetimepicker({
        format: 'hh:mm'        
    });
});
```

As you said you are using [this](http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Clean-jQuery-Date-Time-Picker-Plugin-datetimepicker.html) plugin, you can try using `hours12:true`property too.

**Update**

You can try something like this, your own custom ways.

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-dd-mm',
        onSelect: function(datetext){
            var d = new Date(); // for now
            var h = d.getHours();
                h = (h >12) ? (h-12 + "PM ") : h ;

                var m = d.getMinutes();
            m = (m < 10) ? ("0" + m) : m ;

            var s = d.getSeconds();
            s = (s < 10) ? ("0" + s) : s ;

                datetext = datetext + " " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
            $('#datepicker').val(datetext);
        },
    });
});
```

See the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sibeeshvenu/5qkt8e06/257/)

Comment: yes, when i change to hours12:true,  i am getting only. 1 to 12 am.